# Is there any way to export an existing Google Forms code to the Google Apps Scripts website for other uses?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am working on a project for work involving Google Forms. I have created the Google forms documents that I require but will be unable to host the documents on the Google Forms website for use by my employees. I found that the code for Google Forms at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/ but I was wondering if there is any way to get the code for my existing Google Forms documents and if it is possible to run it elsewhere outside of the docs.google.com / drive.google.com web domains.

Comment: If you want to make your Google Forms code available for other people to use in their Google Form, you can do that with an Add-on.  Then users can install the Add-on in their Google Form.  I'm not sure if that is what you want.